# How can I access a library through a script in a Typescript React app?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, stripe-payments

*I am fairly new to React, and have not done any extensive web development in years, so am struggling with a (probably) basic web issue:*

I am implementing a Stripe based [payment flow](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/server#create-subscriptions) in a React web app (written in Typescript), and have hit a roadblock on [step 2](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/server#add) (adding a redirect to checkout client-side).

The quickstart guide instructs me to insert the following script tag on my website, which I have done through inserting the tag inside the `<head>` tag:

> Checkout relies on Stripe.js. To get started, include the following
>   script tag on your website—it should always be loaded directly from
>   https://js.stripe.com:
>
> ```
>  <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
> ```

The next step is where I am having a **problem** (using the ESNext syntax since this is in a Typescript project):

> Next, create an instance of the Stripe object by providing your publishable API key as the first parameter:
>
> ```
>  const stripe = Stripe('pk_test_sdjxyNjHWmRefdkUNYuS53MA00Ot1f9HOu');
> ```

I would like to access Stripe through a service worker, rather than a component directly. However, trying to initialise the stripe instance is not working. I have tried:

- importing the Stripe module in various ways, which hasn't worked
- adding a dependency on `@types/stripe`, which seems to prevent the compiler complaining

---

Currently, my `StripeService.ts` file has the following code:

```
const stripe = Stripe("SOME_KEY");
export const redirectToCheckout = (sessionId: string) => {
  return stripe.redirectToCheckout(
    {
      sessionId: sessionId,
    });
};
```

Localhost instance is giving this error:

```
/src/services/stripe/StripeService.ts
  Line 12:  'Stripe' is not defined  no-undef
```

Any suggestions on how I can resolve this issue? I have looked into the react-stripe-elements wrapper, but that is geared towards providing UI components, whereas I only want the Stripe checkout API call behaviour.

Comment: You could try installing: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/stripe-v3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Bare Minimum

Minimum implementation is to declare Stripe using `any`:

```
declare class Stripe {
    constructor(...args: any[]);
    redirectToCheckout(...args: any[]): any;
}

const stripe = new Stripe("pk_test_sdjxyNjHWmRefdkUNYuS53MA00Ot1f9HOu");
stripe.redirectToCheckout({
    sessionId: sessionId
})
```

## Stronger Typings

You can of course expand this by more explicitly typing the parts that you need:

```
declare class Stripe {
    constructor(publicKey: string);
    redirectToCheckout({
        sessionId
    }: {
        sessionId: string;
    }): Promise<{ error: Error }>;
}

const stripe = new Stripe("pk_test_sdjxyNjHWmRefdkUNYuS53MA00Ot1f9HOu");
stripe.redirectToCheckout({
    sessionId
}).then(function (result) {
    // If `redirectToCheckout` fails due to a browser or network
    // error, display the localized error message to your customer
    // using `result.error.message`.
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the windows object instead:

```
var stripe = window.Stripe("pk_test_h4naRpZD1t2edp2HQKG2NrZi00rzz5TQJk");
```

Answer (score -3):

For a service file, you would just add `stripe` to `package.json`, then in the file would do:

```
import Stripe from "stripe";
const stripe = Stripe("SOME_KEY");
export const redirectToCheckout = (sessionId: string) => {
  return stripe.redirectToCheckout(
    {
      sessionId: sessionId,
    });
};
```

You would use the public key in the client side, and the secret key in the server side. You should keep stripe object (`Stripe('pk_test_sdjxyNjHWmRefdkUNYuS53MA00Ot1f9HOu')`) in your state somehow to be able to retrieve it later.

An example call could be like this:

*client side*

```
const {paymentMethod, error} = await this.state.stripe.createPaymentMethod('card', cardElement, {
      billing_details: {
      name: 'Jenny Rosen',
   },
});
StripeService.makePayment(paymentMethod);
```

*server side*

```
import Stripe as "stripe";
const stripe = Stripe("SOME_KEY");
export const makePayment = (paymentMethod: object) => {
      ...
};
```

Comment: Currently, the stripe client library is not available as npm module, only the server-side version.

Comment: As @MauriceDöpke said, stripe is not officially available through npm, and I would prefer not to use third-party packages due to security concerns.